# How to merge two High Order Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to merge two High Order Functions (HOFs) in Javascript? Basically I have two arrays using map function to get the item, then sum up with another item from another map function.

e.g.

```
const myArr1 = [
{ attr1: 5, attr2: 9, attr3: 3 },
{ attr1: 4, attr2: 1, attr3: 8 },
{ attr1: 1, attr2: 3, attr3: 1 },
]

const myArr2 = [
{ attr1: 7, attr2: 8, attr3: 5 },
{ attr1: 8, attr2: 2, attr3: 1 },
{ attr1: 3, attr2: 9, attr3: 7 },
]


const map1 = myArr1.map((item) => item);
const map2 = myArr2.map((item) => item);
```

I need to get something like this (expected):

```
const total = [{
   attr1: map1.item.attr1 + map2.item.attr1;
   attr2: map1.item.attr2 + map2.item.attr2;
   attr3: map1.item.attr3 + map2.item.attr3;
}, {...}, {...}]
```

I tried this but did not work as expected:

```
const total = myArr1.map((item1) => {
   myArr2.map((item2) => {
      return [{
         attr1: item1 + item2,
         attr2: item1 + item2,
         attr3: item1 + item2,
      }, {...}, {...}]
   })
});
```

Comment: So the result you expect is `{ attr1: 12, attr2: 3, attr3: 8 }`, right? If not, please explain.

Comment: Yes, { attr1: 12, attr2: 17, attr3: 8 }. Basically I need to build an array with total (arr1 + arr2)

Comment: How are you getting `17` for `attr2`? I did `1 + 2 = 3`.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, and no, you can't use `map` for that. Please try to get it working with simple loops first, so that we can see what you really want to do, and then we can help you using some array iteration methods. Or at least show the expected output, with the actual values for your example, not just "*something like this*". You can [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: map1.item.attr2 + map2.item.attr2

Comment: Oh, so you want an array of total objects?

Comment: yes, exactly, array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is a simple solution to this

```js
const myArr1 = [
  { attr1: 5, attr2: 9, attr3: 3 },
  { attr1: 4, attr2: 1, attr3: 8 },
  { attr1: 1, attr2: 3, attr3: 1 },
];

const myArr2 = [
  { attr1: 7, attr2: 8, attr3: 5 },
  { attr1: 8, attr2: 2, attr3: 1 },
  { attr1: 3, attr2: 9, attr3: 7 },
];

const myArr3 = myArr1.map((fi, i) => ({
  attr1: fi.attr1 + myArr2[i].attr1,
  attr2: fi.attr2 + myArr2[i].attr2,
  attr3: fi.attr3 + myArr2[i].attr3,
}));

console.log(myArr3); 

/** OUTPUT 
[
  { attr1: 12, attr2: 17, attr3: 8 },
  { attr1: 12, attr2: 3, attr3: 9 },
  { attr1: 4, attr2: 12, attr3: 8 }
]
*/
```

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `zip` function to map over two arrays simultaneously:

```
import { zip } from "lodash";

const total = zip(myArr1, myArr2).map(([item1, item2]) => ({
    attr1: item1.attr1 + item2.attr1,
    attr2: item1.attr2 + item2.attr2,
    attr3: item1.attr3 + item2.attr3,
}));
```

Alternatively, you can simplify further with `mergeWith`:

```
import { add, mergeWith } from "lodash";

const total = mergeWith([], myArr1, myArr2, (item1, item2) =>
  mergeWith({}, item1, item2, add)
);
```